# Vector Struct Looplex

Tags: lawtex

"O acesso a um field interno de um vetor deve ser indexado: nome "
Esta mensagem aparece quando tento fazer o upload do meu código, não entendo o que há de errado ao passo que declarei todos os fields, segue código :

```
template[TEMP_BFNProcuracao] { 
    metainfo { 
        language = "pt_BR"
        declarations {
            +<naturezaJuridica> : List ("Pessoa Física" , "Pessoa Jurídica") {
                name = "Natureza Jurídica do cliente"
                request = "O cliente é Pessoa Física ou Pessoa Jurídica?"
                atomic = true 
                default = "Pessoa Física"
            },
            -|clientePf| : Vector [*PessoaFisica] {
                name = "Dados do cliente"
                request = "Insira as informações do cliente"
            },
            -|cliente| : Vector [*PessoaJuridica] {
                name = "Dados da Empresa"
                request = "Insira as informações do cliente"
            },
            +|adv| :  Vector [*Advogado] {
                name = "Dados do Advogado"
                request = "Informe os dados do advogado"
            },
            -<data> : Date ,
            +<procuracao> : List ("ad judicia et extra" , "ad judicia") {
                name = "Procuração"
                request = "Informe o tipo de procuração"
                default = "ad judicia"
                atomic = true 
            },
            +<numeroDoProcesso> : String {
                name = "Número do Processo"
                request = "Informe o número do processo"
            },
            &<prazoDeValidade> : Date {
                name = "Prazo de Validade da Procuração"
                request = "Informe a data de validade da procuração"
            } 
        } 
    } 
    head { 
        title = "Procuração BFN" 
    } 
    body {
        operations {
            use *branch[BRC_Operacoes]
        }
    }
}

// colocar vetor para clientes e advogados 
*branch[BRC_ProcuracaoPF] {
    operations {
        print "Pelo presente instrumento particular, " ,
        beginList("I"),
        foreach(<clientePf> IN |clientePf|) where (separator = "%f; %s; %p; e %l.") {
            print  "\i" & <clientePf.nome> & ", " & <clientePf.nacionalidade> & ", " & <clientePf.estadoCivil> & <clientePf.profissao> & ", RG nº " & <clientePf.rg.numero> & ", residente e domicilidado em " & <clientePf.endereco.logradouro> ,
        if (<clientePf.endereco.logradouro> == "Rua") {
            <endereco.nomeDaRua>.mandatory = "+" ,
            print ", " & <endereco.nomeDaRua>
            }
        else {
            <endereco.nomeDaAvenida>.mandatory = "+" ,
            print ", " & <endereco.nomeDaAvenida>
            },
        print  ", nº " & <clientePf.endereco.numero> ,
        if ( <clientePf.endereco.complemento>.isNotEmpty()) {
            print ", complemento: " & <clientePf.endereco.complemento>
        }, 
        print  "-" & <clientePf.endereco.cidade> & "- Brasil. \n"
        },
        endList(),
        print "  nomeia e constitui seu bastante procurador(es), " ,
        beginList("I"),
        foreach(<adv> IN |adv|) where (separator = "%f; %s; %p; e %l.") {
        print "\i" & <adv.nome> & ", inscrito na OAB/" & <adv.carteira.uf> & "sob o numero " & <adv.carteira.numero> & ", " & <adv.nacionalidade> & ", endereço eletrônico " & <adv.email> & "\n"
        },
        endList(),
        print ", para fim de atuarem profissionalmente, em conjunto ou separadamente, independentemente da ordem de nomeação, outorgando-lhes os poderes da cláusula" &  <procuração> & ", mais os necessários para atuação nos autos, processo nº " & <numeroDoProcesso> & ", podendo substabelecer, no todo ou em parte, os poderes conferidos, e todo o mais que for necessário para o bom e fiel cumprimento do presente mandato. \n" , 
        if (<prazoDeValidade>.isNotEmpty ()) {
            print "Esta procuração é valida até a data do dia "& <procuracao.prazoDeValidade> & "."
        },
        print "\t\n São Paulo, " & <data> & "
        \t\n _________________________________________________"
    }
}

*branch[BRC_ProcuracaoPJ] {
    operations {
        print "Pelo presente instrumento particular, " ,
        beginList("I"),
        foreach(<cliente> IN |cliente|) where (separator = "%f; %s; %p; e %l.") {
            print  "\i" & <cliente.razaoSocial> & ", CNPJ nº " & <cliente.cnpj> & ", com sede em " & <cliente.endereco.via> ,
        if (<cliente.endereco.via> == "Rua") {
            <cliente.endereco.nomeDaRua>.mandatory = "+" ,
            print ", " & <endereco.nomeDaRua>
            }
        elseif (<cliente.endereco.via> == "Avenida") {
                <cliente.endereco.nomeDaAvenida>.mandatory = "+" ,
                print ", " & <cliente.endereco.nomeDaAvenida>
            }
        else {
            <cliente.endereco.nomeDaEstrada>.mandatory = "+" ,
            print ", " & <cliente.endereco.nomeDaEstrada>
        },
        print  ", nº " & <cliente.endereco.numero> ,
        if(<cliente.endereco.complemento>.isNotEmpty()) {
            print ", complemento: " & <cliente.endereco.complemento>
        },
        print  "-" & <cliente.endereco.cidade> & "- Brasil. \n"
        },
        endList(),
        print ", devidamente representada por " & <cliente.representante.nome> & ", RG nº " & <cliente.representante.rg.numero> , 
        if (<ehSocioAdministrador> == true ) {
            print " na qualidade de sócio administrador"
        }
        else {
            print " na qualidade de sócio"
        },
        print "  nomeia e constitui seu bastante procurador(es), " ,
        beginList("I"),
        foreach(<adv> IN |adv|) where (separator = "%f; %s; %p; e %l.") {
        print "\i" & <adv.nome> & ", inscrito na OAB/" & <adv.carteira.uf> & "sob o numero " & <adv.carteira.numero> & ", " & <adv.nacionalidade> & ", endereço eletrônico " & <adv.email> & "\n"
        },
        endList(),
        print ", para fim de atuarem profissionalmente, em conjunto ou separadamente, independentemente da ordem de nomeação, outorgando-lhes os poderes da cláusula" &  <procuração> & ", mais os necessários para atuação nos autos, processo nº " & <numeroDoProcesso> & ", podendo substabelecer, no todo ou em parte, os poderes conferidos, e todo o mais que for necessário para o bom e fiel cumprimento do presente mandato. \n" , 
        if (<prazoDeValidade>.isNotEmpty ()) {
            print "Esta procuração é valida até a data do dia "& <procuracao.prazoDeValidade> & "."
        },
        print "\t\n São Paulo, " & <data> & "
        \t\n _________________________________________________" 
    }
}

*struct[PessoaFisica] {
    name = "Dados Pessoa Física"
    request = "Informe os dados pessoais"
    fields {
        +[nome] : String  { 
            name = "Nome"
            request = "Informe o nome completo"
        },
        +[dataDeNascimento] : Date {
            name = "Data de Nascimento"
            request = "Informe a data de nascimento"
        },
        -[nacionalidade] : List ("Brasileiro" , "Estrangeiro"){
            atomic = true
            default = "Brasileiro"
        }, 
        +[estadoCivil] : List ("Casado(a)" , "Solteiro(a)" , "Divorciado(a)" , "Viúvo(a)" , "Desquitado(a)"){
            name = "Estado Civil"
            request = "Informe o estado civil"
            atomic = true
        },
        -[regimeDeBens] : List ("Comunhão Universal" , "Comunhão Parcial" , "Separação Total") {
            name = "Regime de Bens"
            request = "Qual o regime de bens?"
            atomic = true 
        },
        +[rg] : *RG {
            name = "RG"
        },
        -[cpf] : String where ("\d\d\d.\d\d\d.\d\d\d-\d\d"){
            name = "CPF"
            request = "Informe o número do cpf"
        },
        +[endereco] : *EnderecoPessoaFisica {
            name = "Endereço da Pessoa"
            request = "Informe o Endereço"
        },
        -[conjuge] : *Conjuge
    }
}
*struct[RG] {
    name = "RG"
    request = "Informações do RG"
    fields {
        +[numero] : String { 
            name = "Número do RG"
            request = "Informe o número do RG"
        },
        -[orgaoExpedidor] : String {
            name = "Órgão Expedidor"
            request = "Informe o órgão expedidor"
            default = "SSP"
        },
        -[dataDeEmissao] : Date {
            name = "Data de Emissão"
            request = "Qual a data de emissão do documento?"
        },
        -[uf] : List ("AC", "AL", "AP", "AM", "BA", "CE", "DF", "ES", "GO", "MA", "MT", "MS", "MG", "PA", "PB", "PR", "PE", "PI", "RJ", "RN", "RS", "RO", "RR", "SC", "SP", "SE", "TO") {
            name = "UF"
            atomic = true
            default = "SP"
        }
    }
}
*struct[EnderecoPessoaFisica] {
    fields {
        +[logradouro] : List ("Rua" , "Avenida") { 
            name = "Logradouro"
            request = "Informe a via"
            atomic  = true 
        },
        -[nomeDaRua] : String {
            name = "Nome da rua"
            request = "Informe o nome da rua"
        },
        -[nomedaAvenida] : String {
            name = "Nome da avenida"
            request = "Informe o nome da avenida"
        },
        +[numero] : Integer {
            name = "Número do logradouro"
            request = "Informe o número do logradouro"
        },
        &[complemento] : String {
            name = "Complemento"
            request = "Informe o complemento"
            help = "Se houver complemento, preencha esse campo"
        },
        -[uf] : List ("AC", "AL", "AP", "AM", "BA", "CE", "DF", "ES", "GO", "MA", "MT", "MS", "MG", "PA", "PB", "PR", "PE", "PI", "RJ", "RN", "RS", "RO", "RR", "SC", "SP", "SE", "TO") {
            name = "UF"
            atomic = true
            default = "SP"
        },
        -[cep] : String {
            name = "CEP"
            request = "Informe o CEP"
        },
        -[bairro] : String {
            name = "Bairro"
            request = "Informe o bairro"
        },
        +[cidade] : String {
            name = "Cidade"
            request = "Informe a cidade"
        }
    }
}
// Pessoa Jurídica
*struct[PessoaJuridica] {
    name = "Dados Pessoa Jurídca"
    fields {
        +[razaoSocial] : String { 
            name = "Razão Social"
            request = "Informe a razão social da empresa"
        },
        +[cnpj] : String {
            name = "CNPJ"
            request = "Informe o CNPJ"
        },
        -[socio] : *Socios {
            name = "Informe os dados dos Sócios/Acionistas"
        },
        +[representante] : *Representante , 
        +[endereco] : *EnderecoPessoaJuridica{
            name = "Sede"
        }
    }
}
 *struct[EnderecoPessoaJuridica] {
    fields {
        +[via] : List ("Rua" , "Avenida" , "Estrada") { 
            name = "Endereço"
            request = "Informe a via"
            atomic = true
        },
        +[numero] : Integer {
            name = "Número"
            request = "Informe o número da sede"
        },
        &[complemento] : String {
            name = "Complemento"
            request  = "Informe o complemento"
            help = "Se houver complemento preencha este campo"
        },
        +[uf] : List ("AC", "AL", "AP", "AM", "BA", "CE", "DF", "ES", "GO", "MA", "MT", "MS", "MG", "PA", "PB", "PR", "PE", "PI", "RJ", "RN", "RS", "RO", "RR", "SC", "SP", "SE", "TO") {
            name = "UF"
            atomic = true
            default = "SP"
        },
        +[cep] : String {
            name = "CEP"
            request = "Informe o CEP"
        },
        +[cidade] : String {
            name = "Cidade"
            request = "Informe a cidade"
        },
        +[bairro] : String {
            name = "Bairro"
            request = "Informe o bairro"
        },
        -[nomeDaRua] : String {
            name = "Nome da Rua"
            request = "Informe o nome da rua"
        },
        -[nomeDaAvenida] : String {
            name = "Nome da Avenida"
            request = "Informe o nome da avenida"
        },
        -[nomeDaEstrada] : String {
            name = "Nome da Estrada"
            request = "Informe o nome da estrada"
        }
    }
}
//Advogado
*struct[Advogado] {
    fields {
        +[nome] : String {
            name = "Nome do advogado"
            request = "Informe o nome do advogado"
        },
        +[cpf] : String where ("\d\d\d.\d\d\d.\d\d\d-\d\d") {
            name = "CPF"
            request = "Informe o CPF"
        },
        +[carteira] : *CarteiraOAB {
            name = "Carteira da OAB"
        },
        -[endereco] : *EnderecoPessoaFisica {
            name = "Endereço do Advogado"
        },
        -[escritório] : String {
            name = "Escritório"
            request = "Informe o nome do escritório"
        },
        +[email] : String {
            name =  "Email do Advogado"
            request = "Informe o email do advogado"
        }
    }
}
*struct[CarteiraOAB] {
    fields {
        +[numero] : String { 
            name = "Número da carteira da OAB"
            request = "Informe o número da carteira da OAB"
        },
        +[uf] : List ("AC", "AL", "AP", "AM", "BA", "CE", "DF", "ES", "GO", "MA", "MT", "MS", "MG", "PA", "PB", "PR", "PE", "PI", "RJ", "RN", "RS", "RO", "RR", "SC", "SP", "SE", "TO") {
            name = "UF"
            request = "Selecione o UF da carteira da OAB"
            atomic = true
            default = "SP"
        }
    }
}
*branch[BRC_Operacoes] {
    operations {
        <clientePf.nome> = bold(uppercase(<clientePf.nome>)),
        <cliente.razaoSocial> = bold(uppercase(<cliente.razaoSocial>)),
        <data> = today(expandedDate(<data>)),
        <adv.nome> = bold(uppercase(<adv.nome>)),
        <prazoDeValidade> = expandedDate(<prazoDeValidade>) , 
        if (<naturezaJuridica> == "Pessoa Física") {
            <clientePf>.mandatory = "+" ,
            use *branch[BRC_ProcuracaoPF] 
        }
        elseif (<naturezaJuridica> == "Pessoa Jurídica") {
            <cliente>.mandatory = "+" , 
            use *branch[BRC_ProcuracaoPJ]
        }
    }
}
*struct[Representante] {
    name = "Representante"
    fields {
        +[nome] : String { 
            name = "Nome do representante"
            request = "Informe o nome do representante"
        },
        +[rg] : *RG {
            name = "Dados do rg do representante"
        },
        +[ehSocioAdministrador] : Boolean {
            name = "Sócio Administrador"
            request = "O representante é sócio administrador?"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, edite sua pergunta e tenta colocar em código entre as tags adequadas e identadas. Assim a comunidade pode lhe ajudar com mais facilidade.

Answer (score 0):

Lucas, olhei e testei o seu código, e achei alguns problemas nele:

1. No seu branch `BRC_Operacoes`, você tentou usar diretamente `<clientePF.nome>` e `<cliente.razaoSocial>` (linhas 352 e 353), mas como você inicializou esses elementos como invisíveis, está tentando usar nos tubes (no caso `bold` e `uppercase`), um elemento que ainda não existe em valor, ou seja, é nulo. A mesma lógica para o `<adv.nome>` (linha 355). Para isso, você tem duas soluções:

**a. Adicionar um `if` para checar existência do campo**
Antes de usar o tube, fazer o check:

```
if(<clientePF.nome>.isNotEmpty()) { ...
if(<cliente.razaoSocial>.isNotEmpty()) { ...
if(<adv.nome>.isNotEmpty()) { ...
```

**b. Utilizar o default**
Você pode inicializar o campo nome, da declaração da struct, com um valor de default, para garantir que exista um valor antes do tube ser chamado

```
+[nome]{
    default = "valorPadrão"
}
```

2. Depois de alterar esse campo, encontrei um outro erro na linha 78, em que você usou o nome da variável com acento `<procuração>`, ao invés da versão que você declarou (`<procuracao>`)
3. Encontrei outros problemas, provavelmente semelhantes, com os campos `<endereco>`, mas deixo para que você revise o código e veja se não está chamando alguma operação usando essa `struct` ou algum campo dela antes de iniciá-la.